# How do I treat django's TemporaryUploadedFile as a regular python file

Tags: python, django, file, file-upload

How can I do this? I notice that when you upload a file in django you access it as a TemporaryUploadedFile.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/
There is a method here that gives you the filename if django wrote it to disk. Then you could open it as a standard python file. However, django doesn't write all files to disk by default. I don't want to set django to write all files to disk, for performance reasons.

I just want to pass it into some code that reads the file, expecting a regular python file

Answer (score 0):

If you need something with a file descriptor then you'll have to use [`os.pipe()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pipe). If it just needs a file-like then passing it what you have will do.